# How do I count odd and even amounts of characters with regular expressions?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to pull out all strings which have an even number of B's and an odd number of C's. I have the regexes to match odd A's and even B's but I cannot get the two to work together. The strings are delimited by whitespace (tabs, newlines, spaces).

e.g.

```
XABBAC     ABCDEBCC ABSDERERES ABBAAJSER     HGABAA
```

I have for odd A's

```
\b[^A]*A([^A]*A[^A]*A)*[^A]*\b
```

And for even B's

```
\b[^B]*(B[^B]*B[^B]*)*[^B]*\b
```

I know I need to use +ve lookahead and have tried:

```
\b(?=[^A]*A([^A]*A[^A]*A)*[^A]*\b)[^B]*(B[^B]*B[^B]*)*[^B]*\b
```

but it doesn't work - does anybody know why?

Comment: Seems to work [in ruby](http://rubular.com/r/pcFSTwzklu). Can you give an example where it's not working for you, and also give your Java code?

Comment: @marcog LOL. In ruby this would be a simple one-liner. `data.split.select{|x| x.count("B").even? && x.count("C").odd?}` The result: `["XABBAC", "ABCDEBCC"]`

Comment: "problem"? Seriously? That's what you tag this? As opposed to all the other questions that don't involve some kind of problem?... retagging ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your regexes (regexen?) can match zero characters - `\b\b` will match on a single word boundary, and so will `\b{someregexthatcanmatchzerocharacters}\b`.

Comment: @dr85: Yes, it does. But, it doesn't consume any characters - `\b\b` will match a *single* word boundary; the first `\b` matches a boundary, then the engine tries to match the second `\b`, and it's still at the word boundary, so it matches.

Answer (score 1):

As Anon already mentioned: your pattern matches empty strings, causing `m.find()` to never advance in the target string. So, you need to let your even `B`'s actually match Strings containing 2, 4, 6, ... number of `B`'s. If you want, you can alternate between an even number of `B`'s and this: `[^B\\s]+` (which matches Strings containing 0 `B`'s). As long as you actually match one or more character with it, then you should be okay.

Also, you don't want to look ahead and let the negated classes match spaces: that way you get too much matches.

Try something like this:

```
String text = "XABBAC     ABCDEBCC ABSDERERES ABBAAJSER     HGABAA";

String oddAs = "\\b[^A\\s]*A([^A\\s]*A[^A\\s]*A)*[^A\\s]*\\b";
String evenBs = "\\b([^B\\s]*(B[^B\\s]*B[^B\\s]*)+|[^B\\s]+)\\b";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(String.format("(?=%s)(?=%s)\\S+", oddAs, evenBs));
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

which produces:

```
ABCDEBCC
ABBAAJSER
```

Comment: hi could you explain to me what you are passing in the patter.compile? thanks for the replies. Particularly what is %s?

Comment: @dr85, `String.format` returns a String (the 2 `%s` get replaced  by `oddAs` and `evenBs`). It is the same as doing: `"(?=" + oddAs + ")(?=" + evenBs + ")\\S+"` and feeding that to the static `Pattern.compile(...)` method.

Comment: @dr85, instead of wondering what the code snippet I posted does and doesn't do, why not try it? It does **not** match `ABABABABBA` (I just tested).

Comment: Can I just ask why you use two lookaheads?

Comment: Is it not possible with just one?

Comment: @dr85: You can do it with just one lookahead as you did in your original regex, but @Bart's way is a lot more manageable.  You just have to make sure the regex consumes at least one character.  Once it's consumed the first character, it will go ahead and match the whole word.  But suppose you needed to match *even* numbers of both characters, counting zero as an even number?

Comment: @Bart: That bit with the `|[^B\s]+` isn't really necessary.  You've solved the empty-match problem by adding the `\S+`, so it's okay for the `evenBs` part to match nothing.

Answer (score 1):

With commons.lang.StringUtils it's even more concise:

```
String data = "XABBAC     ABCDEBCC ABSDERERES ABBAAJSER    HGABAA";
String[] items = data.split("\\s+");

for(String item: items ) {
    if (countMatches(item, "B") % 2 == 0
     && countMatches(item, "C") % 2 != 0) {
        System.out.println( item );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

regex is overrated

```
    String str = "XABBAC     ABCDEBCC ABSDERERES ABBAAJSER     HGABAA";
    String[] s = str.split("\\s+");
    for (int j=0 ;j< s.length;j++) {
        int countC=0  ;
        int countB=0;
        for(int i=0;i<s[j].length();i++){
            char c = s[j].charAt(i) ;
            if (c == 'C') countC++;
            if (c == 'B') countB++;
        }
        if ( (countC % 2) != 0 )
            System.out.println( s[j] + " has odd C");
        if ( (countB % 2) == 0 )
            System.out.println( s[j] + " has even B");
    }
```